# Custom sales order report NOT matching Magento's sales order report

Tags: sales-order, reports, collection-filtering

I'm building a custom report sales order using the following code as a start. I'm trying to get all orders that have been updated Yesterday, by passing filters **from date** and **to date** to `sales/order` collection.

```
$date = Mage::getSingleton('core/date');
$formatDate = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
$from_date = $date->gmtDate($formatDate, 'Yesterday 12:00:00AM');
$to_date = $date->gmtDate($formatDate, 'Yesterday 11:59:59PM');

$updated_order_collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('updated_at', array(
    'from' => $from_date,
    'to' => $to_date,
    'date' => true,
))->load();

$updated_count = count($updated_order_collection); // Total order is not matching Magento's sales order report as showon in the screenshot.
```

I was not able to get the same result as Magento's sales order report. The custom code total orders are less than Magento's total orders. See picture below for more details.

[image]

So I'm wondering what I'm missing to get an incorrect total results.

Comment: If you run a query on the DB do you get the same result as your custom report or Magento report? What's the timezone on the DB, on the Admin machine and the one actually configured in the Admin, System -> Configuration -> General -> Locale Options -> Timezone? Also, is `count($collection)` different than `$collection->getSize()`?

Answer (score 1):

Good Morning,

I am not sure if you ever figured this out or not but if you take a look in The `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Report_Order_Collection` class the `__construct` method is using the `sales_order_aggregated_created` table as well as the resource model `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Report_Order`.

I have not created a custom report for this type before but came across these while researching something else.

Hope it helps.

Comment: good afternoon. I was not able to figured this out yet. I'm aware of your suggestion, but still was not able to fine out why I have miss match between my custom report and magento's total ordered report. I'm more interested in detailed report thats why I'm not using the aggregated table to generate my report.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're not getting the same number of results returned because you're adjusting your time (`$from_date`, `$to_date`) to GMT.

As far as I can tell, Magento does not adjust the "from" and "to" dates to GMT when it queries the database for the reports. It really should, but sometimes Magento just lacks consistency. See `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Grid_Abstract`. I've inspected the collection's query, and it literally uses the inputs given.

i.e. `WHERE (period >= '2014-02-01') AND (period <= '2016-03-26')` (`period` is constructed somewhere in the process, but dates are not converted to GMT).

Correct me I'm wrong, of course!